# How do I solve these loop integrals?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, integration, perturbation-theory

If we suppose a $\varphi^3$-theory diagram of self-correction or $\varphi^4$-theory diagram of scattering we encounter an integral

$$\int\frac{d^4q}{(q^2-m^2)((p-q)^2-m^2)}.$$

I have no idea, how to solve it and it also seems to be divergent

If we consider $\varphi^4$ self-correction we get an even more complicated integral

$$\int\frac{d^4q_1d^3q_2}{(q_1^2-m^2)(q_2^2-m^2)((p-q_1-q_2)^2-m^2)}.$$

How does one evaluate those integrals?

Comment: use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_parametrization

Comment: It's QFT. It definitely is divergent in several ways. A huge part of QFT is coming up with appropriate ways of regulating the integral. PS I think this is a legitimate question, and I don't agree it should have been closed as homework-like.